# Playwright second tab is not opened in same session

Tags: pytest, playwright, playwright-python

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def browser_context_args(browser_context_args):
PLAYWRIGHT_STORAGE_STATE.touch(exist_ok=True)
PLAYWRIGHT_STORAGE_STATE.write_bytes(b"{}")

```
return {
    **browser_context_args,
    "storage_state": str(PLAYWRIGHT_STORAGE_STATE.resolve()),
}
```

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def platform_session(
playwright_helpers: PlaywrightHelpers, browser: Browser, authorized_session
) -> Generator[Page, None, None]:
page = browser.new_page()
page.set_extra_http_headers({"Authorization": f"Bearer {authorized_session.token['access_token']}"})
page.goto(playwright_helpers.base_url)
yield page
page.context.storage_state(path=PLAYWRIGHT_STORAGE_STATE)
page.close() this code is supposed to set session for whole session, but in my appliation there is an internal link which opens a new tab, seond tab does not open in same session.

```
  SOME_LINK.click()

    new_page = platform_session.context.pages[-1]
    new_page.bring_to_front()
```

new_page is trying to login rather than opening in same session.